# Font looses it's sharpness when displayed on a page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I have a custom font which I would like to use on my webpage but its edges blur slightly when viewed in Chrome. I have the font on my server and it's linked in CSS.

Comment: I have a feeling adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` to your style will have a role in this.

Comment: test if this helps (text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px)

Comment: (text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px) did nothing